# Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In the `initState(`) method, I use requests to the server when the page is opened, and there is also an `addListener` method that listens for changes to the variable and calls methods if it has changed. But I encountered a small error that appears in the terminal when `addListener` works for me, the application continues to work but a warning constantly appears (I attached a screenshot below). Can you tell me how to get rid of this warning and this is an error, most likely because I do not close `addListener`?

```
@override
  void initState() {
    final appState = Provider.of<AppState>(context, listen: false);
    final ProfileCubit cubit = BlocProvider.of<ProfileCubit>(context);
    final CurrentEmailCubit currentEmailCubit =
        BlocProvider.of<CurrentEmailCubit>(context);
 
      myNotifier.addListener(() {
        if (myNotifier.value?.code != null) {
          SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
            final CurrentEmailCubit currentEmailCubit =
                BlocProvider.of<CurrentEmailCubit>(context);
            await currentEmailCubit.getCurrentEmail();
            currentEmailCubit
                .confirmEmail(
                    code: myNotifier.value?.code ?? '',
                    email: currentEmailCubit.currentEmail)
                .then((value) {
              CodeEmailVerif.code = null;
              myNotifier.value = CodeVerif(value: null);
              if (value) {
                cubit.fetchProfile(context).then((value) {
                  final profileState = cubit.state;
                  if (profileState is ProfileLoaded) {
                    appState.isEmailVerif = profileState.user!.isEmailConfirmed;
                    if (appState.isEmailVerif) {
                      _emailSuccessVerifDialog();
                    }
                  }
                });
              } 
            });
          });
        } 
      });
 
    if (CodeEmailVerif.code != null) {
            final CurrentEmailCubit currentEmailCubit =
                BlocProvider.of<CurrentEmailCubit>(context);
            await currentEmailCubit.getCurrentEmail();
            currentEmailCubit
                .confirmEmail(
                    code: CodeEmailVerif.code ?? '',
                    email: currentEmailCubit.currentEmail)
                .then((value) {
              CodeEmailVerif.code = null;
              myNotifier.value = CodeVerif(value: null);
              if (value) {
                cubit.fetchProfile(context).then((value) {
                  final profileState = cubit.state;
                  if (profileState is ProfileLoaded) {
                    appState.isEmailVerif = profileState.user!.isEmailConfirmed;
                    if (appState.isEmailVerif) {
                      _emailSuccessVerifDialog();
                    }
                  }
                });
              } 
            });
          });
    } else {
        SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
            await currentEmailCubit.getCurrentEmail();
            await cubit.fetchProfile(context).then((value) {
              final profileState = cubit.state;
              if (profileState is ProfileLoaded) {
                appState.isEmailVerif = profileState.user!.isEmailConfirmed;
                if (!appState.isEmailVerif) {
                  _emailDialog();
                } 
              }
            });
          });
    }
    initConnectivity();
    _connectivitySubscription =
        _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_updateConnectionStatus);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _connectivitySubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `mounted` check between `async` operation and updating `ui`. Because your widget can be already `disposed` during `async` operation.

```
await myAsyncFunction();
if (mounted) {
  updateUI();
}
```